# Convert a prepared mysql query to a simple select query

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

How can I convert the following mysql prepared statement to a simple query

```
SET @var_name =  (SELECT settings_table FROM prayertime_table where id = 1);  
SET @s = concat('select device_name from ', @var_name) ; 
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s; 
EXECUTE stmt1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Comment: In a nutshell: you can't. Running a query against a variable table name does require dynamic sql.

Comment: i have seen nested select queries  in 1 query without variables, but was not abe to do it

Comment: You will not be able to have a ***variable*** table name without Dynamic SQL.

Comment: Having a dynamic table name is usually a sign of a bad schema. Use a singular table and if you're having performance problems due to excessive table size, use partitioning.